# How to pass the password in subprocess to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, subprocess

I need superfast response from MySQL, so I am trying to handle this by direct connection to MySQL:

```
command = ['mysql', '-u', 'root', '-p']
proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
(out, err) = proc.communicate("password")
```

But with this code I don't get any response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem this way:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("mysql -h localhost -u root -pMYPASSWORD dbname",
                        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                        shell=True)
```

And now I can make queries:

```
(out, err) = proc.communicate(b"SELECT * FROM AnyTable;")
print("out", out.decode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you're missing in your call to `subprocess.Popen()` is `stdin=subprocess.PIPE`. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate):

> Note that if you want to send data to the process’s stdin, you need to create the Popen object with stdin=PIPE.

```py
proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

However, I'm not sure if that will work still. I would recommend using `pymysql` (https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL).

Here's an example of creating a connection with pymysql:

```py
import pymysql.cursors
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                           user='root',
                           password='password',
                           db='my database',
                           charset='utf8mb4',
                           cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
```